# Trapping and throwing errors when using ExecuteNonQueryAsync which returns Task<int>

Tags: c#, async-await, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, try-catch-finally

When I do the following, I get a warning that not all code paths return a value if the catch block doesn't return an `int`; when that catch block returns an int, the capturedException test for null becomes unreachable unless it is placed inside a `finally` block.  Is putting the throw inside finally{}  acceptable?  Is the connection closed automatically as it would be in a synchronous method that employs the `using` syntax?

```
public async Task<int> Write2Log()
{
  ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {                   
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
      {
         try
           {
         await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
         return await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
           catch (Exception ex)
             {
               capturedException=ExceptionDispatchInfo(ex);
               return -1;
             }

             // unreachable unless placed inside `finally` block
            if (capturedException != null)
              {
                   capturedException.Throw();
              }

      }


  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `try`? Please make sure the code is correct.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the concept of asynchronously calling sql connections, but are you supposed to be returning the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` _there_?

Comment: Can you also explain why do you need to catch the exception?

Comment: Also, it __is__ supposed to be `// unreachable unless placed inside `finally` block`

Comment: @Eric Wu: I have not done any work so far with the async methods in the SQLClient library either. This is new territory for me.  I would like to achieve this (pseudocode) pattern   `Connection.OpenAsync().Success( cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().Success(doSomething() ).Failure( doSomethingElse() )`.

Comment: The whole trick with `await` is that it makes your code perfectly synchronous, while the execution is asynchronous. In the usual scenario, the difference is only in the use of `await` - everything else behaves almost exactly the same as if you used simple synchronous/blocking code. There are gotchas, but the basic approach mirrors C#'s "The simplest solution should also be the most correct solution".

Answer (score 0):

your code in question seems to be incorrect but anyway you need not return in catch.....you can return in end of the method. you know that successful scenario will never reach end of method.

```
public async Task<int> Write2Log()
{
  ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {                   
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
      {

          try
{
         await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
         return await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
           catch (Exception ex)
             {
               capturedException=ExceptionDispatchInfo(ex);

             }

             // unreachable unless placed inside `finally` block
            if (capturedException != null)
              {
                   capturedException.Throw();
              }

      }


  }
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're clumsily trying to write is equivalent to the much simpler

```
public async Task<int> Write2Log()
{
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn)
    {
      await conn.OpenAsync();
      return await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't see why, you might want to refresh your knowledge about how .NET exceptions work, and how `await` works (and in particular, how it handles exceptions).

If you also want to *observe* the exception (e.g. for logging), you can use `throw;` to rethrow the exception at the end of the `catch`. There's no need to use `ExceptionDispatchInfo`, and there's no point in storing the exception in a local to rethrow later.

If you're instead trying to return `-1` when there's an error, just do

```
public async Task<int> Write2Log()
{
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn)
    {
      try
      {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        return await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
      }
      catch
      {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A method cannot throw an exception and return a value at the same time. You have to choose one.

Comment: I admit to being new to async coding, and so clumsiness is to be expected. With `ExceptionDispatchInfo` I was relying upon a heavily upvoted answer here on SO for guidance.

Comment: @Tim Careful about answers you don't understand - it's very likely that there was some specific reason why the solution is complicated. `ExceptionDispatchInfo` is useful when you *don't* `await` the task. When you *do* `await` (or use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`), it's handled automatically for you - it appears as if the code was perfectly synchronous. It's very much possible that the question you referenced is trying to work with pre-`await` code.